# Como executar trigger sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Como posso executar uma **trigger** em testes unitário. Tenho uma **trigger** 
Tenho uma trigger como exemplo:

```
    ***-- Create one trigger with two inserts:***
create trigger trg_I_Table_1 
ON Table_1 
FOR INSERT
as
insert into Table_2 (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) select Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 
from inserted
insert into Table_3 (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) select Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 
from inserted
go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O trigger é executado automaticamente antes ou após a execução dos comandos insert, delete ou update.  Não conheço outra forma de executar um trigger sem a execução desses comandos.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER department insert update   
BEFORE INSÈRT OR UPDATE ON department   
FOR EACH ROW   
DECLARE   dup flag INTEGER;   
BEGIN    
NEW.dept name := UPPER(:NEW.dept name);  
END;
```

Você precisa informar quais comandos irão disparar o trigger, nesse exemplo temos os comandos de insert e update.  O momento que será disparado, no caso seria BEFORE INSERT ou UPDATE department e por fim as atualizações necessárias.